# Ethereum Consortium Blockchain Designed to be Proof of Concept or Production Ready

Tags: microsoft-azure

Is the ***Ethereum Consortium Blockchain*** template in Azure merely designed as a proof of concept platform or is it something you would use for production?

I ask this because if I deploy the Ethereum Consortium Blockchain in my Azure account; am I not technically serving as the "centralized" player in the blockchain since its running in my account, thus defeating the purpose of blockahin?

When reading the description of the template; it states this: This solution deploys an Ethereum simulated multi-member network, consisting of a set of load-balanced transaction nodes with which an application or user can interact to submit transactions and a set of mining nodes to record transactions.

Is this blockchain designed to allow outside nodes to work against it or do all the node VMs have to remain within my azure account?

I certainly appreciate the speed and ease Microsoft has made with creating this template; I just want to try and understand if I wanted to have a production, blockchain that say multiple large clients want to use; this would be the template I would need to use or if I would have to build out something completely different.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally spoke to a blockchain engineer at Microsoft who explained to me that the Azure template for Ethereum can in fact be used for setting up production ready blockchains. If you are wanting to use it as a consortium, other partners in the consortium would just connect up to the nodes within your account. They don't even have to use Azure; they can be within their own data center, etc.